# IIS 6. The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden. The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect.

Tags: c#, razor

I'm new to this project. We are supporting few application.

All our application are in IIS 6.. i.e.. Windows 2003 server. Till last week an application was working fine, no one has changed anything, suddenly started getting the below error

> The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been
>   explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect.
>   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled
>   correctly.

It was a simple application just displaying few guidelines and documents. So it has only the Razor page.

I tried to add the below line in Web.Config file.

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

still the error persists. So tried to add the .cshtml extension to the MIME type in the IIS. Still got the error.

I searched a lot in google and even added the below line in Web.Config file.

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<fileExtensions>
<add fileExtension=".cshtml" allowed="true" />
</fileExtensions>
</requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

Still error persists.

Can somebody help me on this.

Comment: Are you actually going directly to the `.cshtml` page in the URI?

Comment: Have you tried Request Tracing http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5f5bd256-7d1f-4239-9a7f-8eea4072fcb3.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Yes The application directly call the Default.cshtml. ITs not there in the view.. there is no controller as well..